# FOSUserBundle & REST Api Call: How to use custom FormType?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, csrf

I am using FOSUserBundle on my Symfony2 Website. Now I am working on an API to allow registration over a REST api call.

I have overridden the RegistrationController of FOSUserBundle:

**ApiRegistrationController.php:**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/user/", defaults = { "_format" = "json" }, requirements = { "_method" = "POST" })
 * 
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    [...]

    $form = $formFactory->createForm(new ApiRegistrationFormType(), $user);

    [...]
}
```

**ApiRegistrationFormType.php:**

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'BenMarten\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        'intention'  => 'registration',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}
```

I get the error about the wrong CSRF token, so I created my own RegistrationFormType, to disable CSRF - but it is into being called...

How can I achieve disabling the CSRF token only for the api calls?

Comment: How did you create your own RegistrationFormType. You should override FOSUserBundle's RegistrationFormType.

Comment: Yes my class ApiRegistrationFormType is extending the RegistrationFormType of the FOSUserBundle. But it is not picking it up...
this line does not seem to work:     $form = $formFactory->createForm(new ApiRegistrationFormType(), $user);
any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a lot of time fiddling around, I got it working. I hope it saves someone some time.

I use FOSRestBundle.

I have created my own RestController in my bundle:

**RestController.php**

```
namespace BenMarten\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

/**
 * Rest Controller
 */
class RestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new resource
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return View view instance
     *
     */
    public function postUserAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $jsonData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); // "true" to get an associative array

        if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bind($jsonData);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                $response = new Response("User created.", 201);               

                return $response;
            }
        }

        $view = View::create($form, 400);
        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
    }
}
```

**RestRegistrationFormType.php**

```
namespace BenMarten\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

class RestRegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $routeName;
    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container, $class)
    {
        $request = $container->get('request');
        $this->routeName = $request->get('_route');
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($this->routeName != "post_user")
        {
            $builder
                ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
                ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
                ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                    'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                    'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
                ))
            ;
        }
        else
        {
            $builder
                ->add('email', 'email')
                ->add('username', null)
                ->add('plainPassword', 'password')
            ;        
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        if ($this->routeName != "post_user")
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => $this->class,
                'intention'  => 'registration',
            ));
        }
        else
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => $this->class,
                'intention'  => 'registration',
                'csrf_protection' => false
            ));            
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fos_user_rest_registration';
    }
}
```

**Added the service to Services.xml:**

```
<service id="ben_marten.rest_registration.form.type" class="BenMarten\UserBundle\Form\RestRegistrationFormType">
        <tag name="form.type" alias="fos_user_rest_registration" />
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        <argument>BenMarten\UserBundle\Entity\User</argument>
    </service>
```

And in config.yml:

```
registration:
    form:
        type: fos_user_rest_registration
```

So basically I tell the FOS user bundle to use my own registration form and depending on the route i  enable the csrf token or not...

Comment: How should look like json object?
I'm sending that: {
"user" : {
"email":"test@test.pl",
"username":"koper",
"plainPassword":"test"
}
} And still my form is not valid

Comment: without user object: {
"email":"test@test.pl",
"username":"koper",
"plainPassword":"test"
} isn't working too

Comment: ok I have to turn off csrf, but still I've got Integrity constraint violation

Comment: Well if its a integrity constraint violation, it seems to be a database issue. What's the error message exactly?

Comment: what's the point of using a form here? Just for validation? Not sure but if you can skip form here you can save a lot of overhead

Answer (score 2):

## Simpler Please!

Assuming you use both `FOSRestBundle` and `FOSOAuthServerBundle`, you are doing a lot of work for something that is already implemented... I suggest... 2 extra lines in your config file :)

**app/config.yml**

```
# we want to disable csrf roles for users with ROLE_API
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API

# We want to use scope to assign this role when the user requests the token
fos_oauth_server:
        options:
            supported_scopes: user api # https://goo.gl/iE9VoI
```

Et voila!

---

## Now what?

When you request your token with scope api, your user automatically gets the role ROLE_API, and CSRF constraint is gone!

> http://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/v2/token?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECREY&grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD&scope=api

---

Yep, it's in the doc:

- [FOSRestBundle - CSRF Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#csrf-validation)
- [FOSOAuthBundle - Dealing with Scopes](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/dealing_with_scopes.md)

Comment: To make an oauth call you need username and password right? How do you get that in the first place? I think this question is about registration. Once you have a username password in the database then you can get access_token