# FOSRestBundle How to validate the registration?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I'm developing a RESTFul API in Symfony 2.3.* with FOSUserBundle and FOSRestBundle, and I'm having trouble understanding how to create a registration method.

My controller look like this :

```
class UserRestController extends FOSRestController
{
    //Other Methods ...

    public function postUserAction()
    {
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->createUser();

        $param = $paramFetcher->all();
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
        $form->bind($param);

        if ($form->isValid() == false)
            return $this->view($form, 400);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        return $this->view('User Created', 201);
    }

    //...
}
```

And my UserType class :

```
class UserType extends BaseType
{
    public function __construct($class = "User")
    {
        parent::__construct($class);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username', 'username')
                ->add('email', 'email')
                ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                   'first_name' => 'password',
                   'second_name' => 'confirm',
                   'type' => 'password'
                ))
                ->add('lastname')
                ->add('firstname')
                ->add('job_position')
                ->add('phone')
                ->add('company_name')
                ->add('website')
                ->add('sector')
                ->add('address')
                ->add('city')
                ->add('zip_code')
                ->add('country')
                ->add('billing_infos_same_as_company')
                ->add('billing_address')
                ->add('billing_city')
                ->add('billing_zip')
                ->add('billing_country')
                ->add('putf')
                ->add('das');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Wipsea\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'wipsea_user_registration';
    }
}
```

When I test it, no matter what the form isn't valid and shows no error.
And when I try to get the request :

"Validation Failed" "This form should not contain extra fields."

Is there a way to properly validate the form ?

EDIT : Updating my problem.

Comment: Take a look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22394282/453348)

Comment: I'm pretty new to symfony and I don't understand most of the answer's code. Like the dispatcher role.

Comment: It seems that this answer isn't adapted for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you this tutorial in 3 parts - there is everything you need:

- http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/
- http://welcometothebundle.com/web-api-rest-with-symfony2-the-best-way-the-post-method/
- http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-way-part-3/

If you want to provide complex user validation you should create UserType form and pass data to this form instead of directly setting all properties:

```
public function postAction()
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
    $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // propel version
        $user->save();

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(201);

        // set the `Location` header only when creating new resources
        $response->headers->set('Location',
            $this->generateUrl(
                'acme_demo_user_get', array('id' => $user->getId()),
                true // absolute
            )
        );

        return $response;
    }

    // return form validation errors
    return View::create($form, 400);
}
```

In part 2 of this tutorial you have all information about creating form, passing data and validating it with RestBundle.

There is also a lot information about best practices using REST with Symfony2.

Comment: Please let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: I do as a matter of fact. I finished My UserClass (with FOSRest) and made a UserType.php
I can't figure why it won't validate when I test the post Route with the correct infos, because when I get the errors, it tells me there's no errors.

Comment: One more thing: please paste your entity class because you are using annotation that you forget to import. How do you test it? Unit tests?

Comment: I'm testing it with Postman RestClient and the thing is I don't use the @Enum annotation, and even if I import it, the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

https://github.com/piotrjura/fitness-api/blob/master/src/Fitness/FitnessBundle/Service/UsersService.php#L40

https://github.com/piotrjura/fitness-api/blob/master/src/Fitness/FitnessBundle/Controller/UsersController.php#L30

Also check validation.yml and entity serializer yml files.

You don't need forms to do the validation. And you definitly should not put the user creation and validation logic inside a controller. In case you'd like to make use of that form anyway later, eg. render it on the backend side, you'll have to write the same code twice.

Comment: That's considered a bad practice for REST. I want to validate with a form, I know it's possible, but I cannot validate the form. I don't know how.

Comment: If you need to do the validation using forms, this might help you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes. Check out the first hint, it says: "When mapping forms to objects, all fields are mapped. Any fields on the form that do not exist on the mapped object will cause an exception to be thrown.". Make sure all fields map to your entity correctly (eg. password repating field).

Answer (score 0):

I had to have the getName() method return '' in order for it to work for me.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/585