# How to know uploaded file size on symfony 3?

Tags: php, file, symfony, file-upload

i use FOSRestbundle to manage my api. I implemented a action to upload a file on symfony that it's working well. But the problem is that i need to obtain the file size... My action get the file on this way:

```
$uploadedfile = $request->files->get('file');
```

this obtains an array of all files that i upload.

Reading the doc of symfony for the $uploadedfile object, there is a method called:

```
getClientSize()
```

so i used and always return 0:

```
$fileSize = $uploadedfile->getClientSize();
```

There are another way to get the file size? I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: might be an error happened when uploading?
try to call getError to see what error. 
what happen when you call the other member of that class? such as getClientOriginalName?

Comment: The file upload fine my friend. The problem is that value is always = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about the solution here?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "1024k",
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PDF"
     * )
     */
    protected $bioFile;
}
```

you might have to create an entity for that, if you have not done so.

So if you want to use validation in your controller, you would do something like

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Author;

// ...
public function authorAction()
{
    $author = new Author();

    // ... do something to the $author object

    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($author);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {

        $errorsString = (string) $errors;

        return new Response($errorsString);
    }

    return new Response('The author is valid! Yes!');
}
```

you can test it, by uploading a file larger than the maxsize, set in your given `Author` Entity in that case you would get the message *"Please upload a valid PDF"*

Comment: Hi @Confidence thanks for your answer, can you please give me an example of how can i use it? Or where can use this inside my controllers? Thanks

Comment: Thanks my friend! But... i use symfony only as backend, with a REST Api. I don't use any form for the view... this will work anyway?

Comment: it should work, if you create your object in the same way, for example from the uploaded data or the given query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully moved the file into the intended folder? if you have, you can just call a native php function filesize().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: That's a problem my friend because i need to know the file size before move to a folder... I need to compare this file size with the php.ini directive before to throw my custom error of file size not permited...

Comment: could you look on this one, http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#uploadinisizeerrormessage

this will take care of your validation/constraint, but seems to use this you need to change your structure a bit.

Comment: Thanks @r4ccoon... can you please give me an example to use this with my FOSRestControllers? Im so new using symfony

Comment: On the same link, you can see section "Basic Usage". basically, you need to create your entity, in this page, the use case is Author which has "biofile".
Basically in symfony you need Entity, and Form. Entity where you put your constraint, such as this one, and Form where it can check for the constraints.
related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509486/fosrestbundle-how-to-validate-the-registration

Comment: Thanks my friend! But... i use symfony only as backend, with a REST Api. I don't use any form for the view... this will work anyway?